# Multiplicar números de 2 input y obtener resultado automático sin refrescar la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy armando un sitio web con el cual trabajo con tabla de productos y necesito hacer que al elegir la cantidad de un producto se multiplique por el valor por unidad y que el resultado se muestre automático.

Sé hacer esto, pero no de manera automática. Si alguien sabe me podría ayudar.

PD: Estoy utilizando PHP, javascript y MySQL.

Comment: Por favor considera agregar lo que llevas al momento

Comment: ¿Qué te falla en el código? ¿Puedes compartir al menos el código HTML de los campos `<input>`?

Comment: Puedes usar el evento onchange de un input y controlarlo a través de javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con javascript lo puedes hacer, agrega la siguiente función a tu botón (en el que tiene asignado el evento)

```
function multiplicar(){
  m1 = document.getElementById("multiplicando").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador").value;
  r = m1*m2;
  document.getElementById("resultado").value = r;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres crear contenido dinámico, estás obligado a utilizar algún lenguaje de programación del lado del cliente.
Te recomiendo conocer las bases de javascript y luego potenciarlo con Jquery que en resumen, es un conjunto de funcionalidades hechas con javascript para que tú escribas menos código.

Te  dejo un ejemplo del código que necesitas en javascript utilizando Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#inputNumerico1').change(function(){ 
          var resultadoSuma = $('#inputNumerico1').val() + $('#inputNumerico2').val();              
         $('#labelResultado').text(resultadoSuma);
     });
     $('#inputNumerico2').change(function(){ 
          var resultadoSuma = $('#inputNumerico1').val() + $('#inputNumerico2').val();              
         $('#labelResultado').text(resultadoSuma);
     });
 });
```

Cabe señalar que para utilizar Jquery necesitas importarlo a través de una etiqueta html script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me a funcionado con muy poco codigo

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que la parte de PHP la tienes correctamente controlada, por lo que te comento cómo hacer la parte que se ejecuta en el navegador presuponiendo que sabes cómo realizar los cambios necesarios en PHP:

```js
/* Cada vez que cambiemos la cantidad se actualizará el nuevo subtotal */
document.querySelectorAll('tbody input[type="number"]').forEach(elemento => {
  /* Cada vez que se produzca un cambio en una cantidad actualizamos */
  elemento.addEventListener('change', e => {
    /* El "input" tiene como padre a "td" y luego al "tr" que nos interesa */
    let fila = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
    /* Buscamos el precio */
    let precio = parseFloat(fila.querySelector('[data-precio]').dataset.precio);
    /* Tenemos la cantidad */
    let cantidad = parseFloat(e.currentTarget.value);
    fila.querySelector('[data-subtotal]').dataset.subtotal = precio * cantidad;
    /* Calculamos el total a partir de la suma de subtotales */
    let total = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-subtotal]').forEach(elemento => {
      total += parseFloat(elemento.dataset.subtotal);
    });
    document.querySelector('[data-total]').dataset.total = total;
  })
});
```

```css
[data-precio]:before {
 content: attr(data-precio) ' €';
}
[data-subtotal]:before {
 content: attr(data-subtotal) ' €';
}
[data-total]:before {
 content: attr(data-total) ' €';
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Subotal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Zapatillas deportivas</td><td data-precio="85.50"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" /></td><td data-subtotal="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jersey muy chulo</td><td data-precio="15.90"></td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" /></td><td data-subtotal="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" align="right">Total:</th>
      <th id="total" data-total="0"></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por darte el tiempo de ayudarme funciona a la perfección, pero como soy novato en esto poco entiendo algunas lineas de codigo pero de todos modos lo guarde para poderlo reutilizar a futuro.

Comment: Pregunta lo que necesites y trato de explicarlo con comentarios en el código o en un comentario.

Comment: muchas gracias tendré presente lo dicho

Comment: ¿disculpa me puede ayudar o explicar algo?

Comment: No es necesario que preguntes si me puedes preguntar. Si es acerca de esta pregunta o respuesta lo puedes hacer aquí mismo, como comentario. Si es una duda nueva redacta una nueva pregunta y déjame un comentario por aquí para que le eche un vistazo.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331281/como-puedo-pasar-datos-de-una-tabla-html-que-esta-cargada-con-mysql-a-inputs

Comment: en el siguiente enlace realice una pregunta. si fuera tan amable de darme una solucion

Comment: Esta noche (en unas 5 o 6 horas) podré echarle un vistazo.

Comment: si muchas gracias estaré atento a sus respuestas :)