# ¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de una tabla HTML, que está cargada con MySQL, a inputs?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

He creado una tabla HTML a la cual le he pasado datos desde MYSQL. Me funciona correcto, se muestran en orden todos los registros, pero resulta que tengo un formulario y necesito que los `<input>` se llenen al hacer clic en la fila de mi tabla. Que se le pase todos los valores almacenados de la fila de mi tabla a los `<input>`.

```
<table id="tablaMaterialesEiser">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th title="Nombre de el Material">NOMBRE</th>
          <th title="Marca de el Material">MARCA</th>
          <th title="Modelo de el material">MODELO</th>
          <th title="Valor por Unidad de el material">VALOR</th>
          <th title="Modelo de el material">AGREGAR</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody border-collapse: style="background-color:#EAECED;">
        <?php
        $query     = "SELECT * FROM vista_materiales_eiser";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td title="<?php echo $row['Nombre'] ?>"><?php echo $row['Nombre'] ?></td>
            <td title="<?php echo $row['Marca'] ?>"><?php echo $row['Marca'] ?></td>
            <td title="<?php echo $row['Modelo'] ?>"><?php echo $row['Modelo'] ?></td>
            <td title="$<?php echo number_format($row['Valor'], 2, ",", ".") ?>">$<?php echo number_format($row['Valor'], 2, ",", ".") ?></td>
            <td style="width:20px;"><a title="agregarMaterial" class="btn btn-success" href="AgregarMaterial.php?idMaterial=<?php echo $row['IdMaterial'] ?>">+</a></td>

          </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Luego el formulario:

```
    <form>

<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputPassword4">Nombre Material</label>
<input  type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Nombre Material">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputPassword4" >Valor</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Valor">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputPassword4" >Cantidad</label>
<input  class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Cantidad">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputPassword4">Total</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Total">
</div>
</div>
<input class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Agregar">
</form>
```

Cabe destacar que quiero hacerlo sin que se refresque mi página, porque tengo otros datos que le muestro al usuario y no tiene sentido recargarla.

Comment: ¿Podrías modificar tu pregunta para ayudarte con un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Si además incorporas la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y podríamos montar el ejemplo e intentar darte una solución. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: ok ya lo modifique espero que se entienda

Comment: Para hacer lo que quiere debe haber una implementación desde javascript, la tiene hecha? si es así, la podría mostrar?

Comment: No aun no tengo nada en javascript, no se como implementar lo que quiero con javascript.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar con un poco más de detalle paso a paso qué es lo que deseas hacer? Es decir, no entiendo cuando dices lo de "necesito que los `<input>` se llenen al hacer clic en la fila de mi tabla". ¿Al hacer clic en una fila en cualquier sitio? ¿En un botón? ¿Con qué datos?

Comment: resulta que tengo una tabla con un contenido x,, y en cada fila hay un boton que se llama agregar, al pulsarlo quiero que me pase todos los campos de esa fila a los input de mi formulario, por ejemplo si doy click al articulo 1 me pase el nombre a un input  que contendrá ese nombre, luego otro el campo siguiente a otro input que contendrá ese campo,,, y asi sucesivamente. espero haber sido lo mas claro posible

Comment: ¿Entoces tratas de hacerlo como una [ventana modal de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)? Necesitaría ver el código con el que abres el modal para hacer allí las modificaciones.

Comment: Hola estimado le comento que logre hacer lo que buscaba por medio de ajax. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Pero ajax envía los datos del formulario a un php para actualizar la base de datos sin recargar la página, no rellena los input del formulario con los datos que hay en la fila de la tabla que pulsas. Por lo que dices creo que no explicaste bien lo que querías hacer. Recuerda que lo que tienes claramente en tu mente no tiene por qué ser tan claro para otras personas. Me alegra que lo hayas solucionado. Por cierto, recuerda nombrar con un @ a la persona a la que te diriges para que le llegué una notificación. En caso contrario solo veo tu respuesta si por casualidad vuelvo a esta pregunta.

Comment: Si @OscarGarcia, no tenia conocimiento de eso de nombrar con @ , y muchas gracias por tu buena voluntad espero poder acudir a ti en caso de algún problema en programación

Comment: Por lo pronto te recomiendo que cambies los `<?php echo $variable; ?>` por `<?= htmlspecialchars($variable) ?>` para evitar [problemas de XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Y, por cierto, en la otra pregunta marcaste como correcta una que solo funciona para multiplicar un valor por una cantidad, mientras que solicitabas poder hacerlo con múltiples filas de una tabla. Espero que trabajar con la manera que marcaste como correcta no complique el código de tu página en exceso (que lo hará).

Comment: @OscarGarcia si estimado en realidad yo me exprese mal. pero el código que compartiste lo tengo considerado y lo utilizare ya que me servirá para una parte que desarrollare mas adelante en mi proyecto. pero agradezco y valoro todas tus respuesta.